# Не сохраняется аватар через форму

Tags: python, django

Загружаю фотографию через форму, страница обновляется, а аватар не меняется

```
models py:

class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="cabinet/img/")
  vk = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
  instagram = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user
```

```html
forms.py

class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'}), required=False)
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5}), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'bio']
```

```html
views.py
   
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user = Profile.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Ваш профиль успешно обновлен и ')
            return redirect(to='users-profile')
    else:
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    return render(request, 'cabinet/user_profile.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'user1': user})
```